# count_values with known levels of a variable

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for an efficient way of computing pivot_tables and frequency counts but my requirement is that if I know the domain of a variable, then the counts for every value in the domain should be done, not only those values that are observed in the samples.

For instance with the code below, the Series.count_values method outputs :

```
2    2
1    2
```

But I know that the domain of my variable is [0,1,2] so I really want :

```
0    0
1    2
2    2
```

Here's a sample of code to reproduce the example

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s=pd.Series([1,2,2,1])

def my_value_counts(s,levels):
#levels is a numpy array
    c=s.value_counts()
    foundl=sorted(c.index)
    counts=np.zeros_like(levels)
    for i,l in enumerate(levels):
        if l in foundl:
            counts[i]=c.loc[l]
    return counts

print "Original method"
print s.value_counts()
print "with all levels"
print my_value_counts(s,np.arange(3))
```

My question is : is my code inefficient ? Seems like a bit of sorting could help. And if so, is there a way to do this without having to re-create a frequency table and matching its values to the output of values_count like I did in the code ?

Thanks,
AL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [80]: pd.Series([1,2,2,1]).value_counts().reindex(np.arange(3))
Out[80]: 
0   NaN
1     2
2     2
dtype: float64

In [81]: pd.Series([1,2,2,1]).value_counts().reindex(np.arange(3)).fillna(0)
Out[81]: 
0    0
1    2
2    2
dtype: float64
```

Comment: this appears pretty much identical to my answer

Comment: Indeed it is. I might have deleted my answer after I saw yours (rather than merely voting for it), but OP had asked me personally out of band about the problem and I wanted to follow through.

Comment: I'd also suggest that my answer is ever-so-minutely better since (a) I explicitly show the NaN that you'd get before fillna-ing, which is often fine rather than the 0 (depending on what one wants to do), and (b) it doesn't suggest the `max_value_actually_seen + 1` trick, which seems a bit wrong-headed when the intent was to know a priori the possible values. (It wouldn't  work with starting data like `[0, 1, 1, 0, 1]`, when we'd still want to know the count for 2 was 0.)

Comment: but in my answer it's unknown the range as such only that it's 0 to the max value which is why I propose a dynamic method

Comment: @EdChum, I realize it's unknown in your answer, which I think is unfortunate and a mismatch with the question / the underlying problem.

Answer (score 3):

One method would be to `reindex` the value_counts with a new index starting from 0 to the max value + 1:

```
In [12]:
s=pd.Series([1,2,2,1])
val = s.value_counts()
val.reindex(np.arange(0, s.max()+1)).fillna(0)

Out[12]:
0    0
1    2
2    2
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Efficient?  Probably.  Elegant?  Less so.

```
s.value_counts().combine_first(pd.Series(np.zeros(3)))
```